# How to distinguish trigger actions in sql?

Tags: sql, triggers, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'd like to create on Trigger that is fired on insert, update and delete.
Inside the trigger I need to handle those actions in different ways.
How can I find out which action triggered the trigger ?
Or, should I use multiple triggers for different actions ?

'if update(FIRSTNAME)' works fine, but how to differentiate insert and delete?
'if insert(FIRSTNAME)' obviously does not work.

```
ALTER TRIGGER "FR_CHANGES" AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
ORDER 1 ON "DBA"."PERSONAL"
referencing old as old_rec new as new_rec
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if update(FIRSTNAME) or update(LASTNAME) then
       insert into FR_CHANGES (PNR_PERSONAL, CHANGE_TYPE) values (old_rec.PNR, "update")  
    end if
    if insert(FIRSTNAME) then //this line gives an error
       insert into FR_CHANGES (PNR_PERSONAL, CHANGE_TYPE) values (new_rec.PNR, "insert")  
    endif
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish by the existance of the row in the virtutal table insert/delete, like that:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (select * from deleted)
BEGIN

print 'actions after insert statement'


END
ELSE IF EXISTS (select * from inserted) AND EXISTS (select * from deleted)
BEGIN


print 'actions after update statement'

END

ELSE IF EXISTS (select 1 from deleted) AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from inserted)
BEGIN

print 'actions after delete statement'

END
```

Comment: When changing it this way, I get a "syntax error" in line 8. This is the second "begin" command in the trigger.  ALTER TRIGGER "FR_CHANGES" AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
ORDER 1 ON "DBA"."PERSONAL"
referencing old as old_rec new as new_rec
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (select * from inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (select * from deleted)
        BEGIN
            print 'actions after insert statement'
        END

END

Comment: Isn't it ELSEIF in Sybase?

Comment: If I do    select * from inserted, I get the message that there is no such table

Comment: These tables will only recognized within trigger definition.

Comment: unfortunatly the same error (table inserted does not exist) when executed inside a Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You could discriminate between an insert & delete event by smth like this, perhaps

```
alter trigger trg_test_table 
on test_table for insert, delete 
as 
begin
  print 'inside trigger'
if (select count(*)     from deleted) > 0 
  begin 
    print 'test_table delete'
  end
if (select count(*)     from inserted) > 0 
  begin 
    print 'test_table insert'
  end
end
;
```